# Explore and pick up properties of a multi level object

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a multi-level object with definition of different objects in it. Some of these properties 'leafs' are default and contains a default value.

I need to construct another object in javascript, with the same 'path' to the leaf but with the default value as the value of the property.

It's ok with all the objects on the same 'floor' with a simple for on the object and hasOwnProperty. But here, it seems to me that it's more a while that I need to explore the object, and I don't know how to address the object as I can't use something like object[iter1.iter2.iter3...]. 
I need to mention that I'm working on a Service Now Server in an Eureka version, so it is supporting only ECMAScript 3.

There is an example :

- objet I need to process (json encoded):

  ```
  "schema": {"properties": {
      "videoCapability": {
          "default": "1",
          "type": [
              "string"
          ],
          "choices": [
              {
                  "value": "0",
                  "title": "Disabled"
              },
              {
                  "value": "1",
                  "title": "Enabled"
              }
          ],          },
      "ice": {
          "properties": {
              "iceCapability": {
                  "default": "1",
                  "type": [
                      "string"
                  ],
                  "choices": [
                      {
                          "value": "0",
                          "title": "Disabled"
                      },
                      {
                          "value": "1",
                          "title": "Enabled"
                      }
                  ],
                  "name": "iceCapability","
              },
              "defaultcandidatetype": {
                  "default": "0",
                  "type": [
                      "string"
                  ],
                  "choices": [
                      {
                          "value": "0",
                          "title": "Host"
                      },
                      {
                          "value": "1",
                          "title": "Server Reflexive"
                      },
                      {
                          "value": "2",
                          "title": "Relayed"
                      }
                  ],
              },
      etc.
  ```
- Object I need to build :

  ```
              "config": { config.properties.videoCapability = "1"
                  config.properties.ice.properties.iceCapability = "1"
                  config.properties.ice.properties.defaultcandidatetype = "0"
              }
  ```

etc.

If you wonder why I need to do this, it's that the first object is retreived in json from a distant server. After encode this json to an object, I need to modify some properties with the rigth values but not all. And I need to send back the object (decoded) to the distant server.

Comment: Your "Object I need to build" is not valid syntax. do you mean `{"config.properties.videoCapability": "1"}`?

Answer (score 0):

`lodash.get` can be useful here:

Given this object:
`{ a: { b: { c: { d: { e: { f: { g: {h : 1}}}}}}}}`

`_.get(obj, 'a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h')` returns 1

If one of those objects is not defined, the operation will return `undefined` rather than throwing.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution by generalizing the one property solution without adding external libraries. It gives a recursive function that returns a new object :

```
exploreObject : function (source, target, value, n) {
    if(n > 10000) // just to avoid infinite loop
        return;

    for(var i in source) {
    //for every property in the source
        if(source[i].hasOwnProperty('default')){
        // if the property contains default values, set the same property in the target object to the default values 
            target[i] = source[i]['default'];
            if (i == 'videoCapability' || i == 'ciscoCamera'){
            //in my case, I had properties that needed to be changed from default to the 'value' value
                target[i] = value;
            }
        } else if (typeof source[i] == 'object' && source[i] != null ){
        //if the property doesn't contains default values and if it is an object, then we have to inspect this object
            if (i == 'properties' && !NbPair(n)) {
            //With JSON object, it can contains artefact property (with impair values of 'deepness' n), because coding to JSON can add a property 'properties' to store the properties. We don't need it, the values will be added to target object and not to target.properties
                target = this.exploreObject(source[i], target, value, n + 1);
            } else {
            //target[i] has to be an object to store the new properties
                target[i] = {};
                target[i] = this.exploreObject(source[i], target[i], value, n + 1);
            }
            if (typeof target[i] == 'object' && isEmpty(target[i]) == true){
            //After the call to the function itself, we delete the newly added object if it is empty (did not contained any default property, or the default value was empty)
                delete target[i];
            }
        }
    }

    return target; //return the object with correct values

    function isEmpty(obj) {
    //function used to check if the object is empty
        for(var key in obj) {
            if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    function NbPair(Nb){
    //function used to check if the 'deepness' in the object is pair or impair
        if(Nb/2 == Math.round(Nb/2))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
},
```